# Understanding session in a large asp.net application

Tags: javascript, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, web-applications

I have an unusual web application similar in some ways to the live versions of [DriveWorks](http://www.driveworkspro.com/) and [KBmax](http://www.kbmax.com/home). The Logic, Interface, and Tables are created in a windows application by sales teams and engineers throughout the company and stored in sql server. In the Web application, when a user clicks an item in the product menu the the Logic and Interface are pulled from the database, compiled using CodeDOM into an InMemory executable and stored in Session variable. The Front interface in web application is dynamic and invokes the executable in session for the control logic events. The Tables are also stored in a DataSet in Session. At any rate, this all actually works, but seems to have random quirks that are hard to pinpoint. I'm wondering if this is way to much to put in session and alternatives.

Note: I am using javascripting where I can, however since the code is actually created by other users there is also a lot of postbacks going on. When I run this using my localhost it seems to run acceptable, but on the host server it seems clunky.
I have this same application as a Windows application and it works great, just trying to make the web version.

Comment: The more you put in the session the bigger the load on the server. Basic rule is more users therefore increased session usage, so more RAM required. Have you looked at loading the required code etc. on every page load? Remember if you are using load balancing without server affinity you will have to use a session server or SQL Server session storage.

Comment: @JamesCulshaw Yup, I only load the code and dataset once. however i have to create the 50+ dynamic interface controls on every postback. I guess i am not familiar with session server, i will look into that.

Comment: @JamesCulshaw I meant to say I wasn't familiar with SQL Server session storage. I looked into it but seems like it might be slower. When I run the Application using localHost it runs very fast. Is there perhaps some other settings on the host server that could speed things up?

Answer (score 0):

If 64bit process is used, using session should not be a problem. If 32 bit process is used you should look at out-proc (db / windows server AppFabric). Regarding random quirks, i guess something to do with code.

Comment: do you mean for Target CPU or compiling CodeDOM executable? I guess im not sure.

Comment: I mean w3wp process..In IIS there is a setting to indicate whether process should be 32 or 64 bit (this option is only for 64 bit server). Target cpu you will leave it any cpu if there is no reference to com.